# When using set in DataFrame to remove duplicate words in list, the words changed (not about the order)

Tags: python, pandas, set

I am using set in a dataframe to remove duplicate words in a list, but the original words changed in the result.

these are the words shown in dataframe:

[Which, one, dissolve, in, water, quickly, sugar, ,, salt, ,, methane, and, carbon, di, oxide, ?]

note: words like 'sugar,' and 'salt,' are with comma

these are the result shown in dataframe after using set:
{oxide, sugar, Which, di, water, in, ,, salt, carbon, dissolve, one, ?, methane, quickly, and}

```
data['sent1']=data['sent1'].apply(lambda x : set(x))
```

I want the words to keep the same order after using set.
I really get puzzled why set will change the original words(form'sugar,'to'sugar')

Comment: Are you referring to the order of the words?

Comment: no, I mean the set operation changes 'sugar, ' to 'sugar' in the result. note that there is a comma in the original words

Comment: doesn't sound like the behavior of a set operation. i think you need to double check your code

Answer (score 0):

If each row in your data frame looks like this:

```
data.loc[0, "sent1"] = ["Which", "one", "dissolve", "in", "water", "quickly", "sugar", ",", "salt", ",", "methane", "and", "carbon", "di", "oxide", "?"]
```

Then you could append the comma before applying the set operation, like:

```
data['sent1'] = data['sent1'].apply(lambda x: set([i + "," for i in x]))
```

On the other hand, f each row in `data['sent1']``is one long string of words:

```
data.loc[0, "sent1"] = ["Which", "one", "dissolve", "in", "water", "quickly", "sugar", ",", "salt", ",", "methane", "and", "carbon", "di", "oxide", "?"]
```

then try:

```
data['sent1'] = data['sent1'].apply(lambda x: set(x.split(" ")))
```

Comment: @jonathanschum Glad it helped and welcome to SO! Feel free to accept the answer and upvote.